# Do I need to provide a copy of my UK itinerary when applying for a Schengen visa, if I'm visiting both territories in one trip?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork

My UK visit was approved yesterday. I am planning on visiting the UK in June and right after Spain. Do I provide the Spanish embassy with my planned itinerary for the UK as part of of my application?

Comment: No and not required. Why do you want to furnish this information ? Your visa sticker will be in your passport for them to see, if they care.

Comment: If you are re-entering the zone after your UK visit, then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: Your question is not clearly worded. Do you mean you will visit UK right after you visit Spain, or you will visit UK and then immediately after that you will visit Spain? Clarify.

Comment: Spain after the UK

Answer (score 2):

No, you're only required to submit your itinerary for Spain (such as hotel bookings), along with proof of how you're entering/exiting (i.e. a ticket on either Eurotunnel or a ferry).

It will make sense to the visa officers seeing as you already have a UK visa